# PHP explode a string but keep the serialized part intact

Tags: php

I am trying to take a string, which is actually part of a insert statement, explode it ( it is separated by commas ) and then test reform the string depending on the index of the value. I have everything done but realize that exploding by a comma while potentially having a serialized value with the whole string as its own value will actually explode that serialized value which throws the whole thing off. Im trying to avoid having to go back and check before creating the string, that would be very involved but might be my only option. I was wondering if there is a way to take the initial string and separate it by the commas without separating the actual serialized value within the string. An example is below.

```
 NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'hello world','a:3:{s:6:"johnny";a:3:{s:7:"physics";s:9:"great job";s:5:"maths";s:19:"you did a, good job";s:9:"chemistry";s:27:"need to work on this, johny";}s:5:"brady";a:3:{s:7:"physics";s:9:"great job";s:5:"maths";s:19:"you did a, good job";s:9:"chemistry";s:27:"need to work on this, brady";}s:5:"keith";a:3:{s:7:"physics";s:9:"great job";s:5:"maths";s:19:"you did a, good job";s:9:"chemistry";s:27:"need to work on this, keith";}}',NULL,23,14
```

Comment: Consider using [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) instead

Comment: I'm not clear on what this "*example*" represents exactly. Is this a string? Where is the data coming from? Why are you concatenating serialized and unserialized data and then trying to split them? The very mention of ***part of a insert statement*** both frightens and horrifies me, because it leads me to believe you are doing something terribly evil with your SQL, when there could be a much safer, saner, simpler, sweeter, superior solution. A lot of alliteration, I know.... But please can you explain what your real goal is?

Comment: @MarkBaker Also, `str_getcsv()` doesn't work here, because he has PHP serialized data, which can include a mixture of quotes with no escape character, meaning that serializing an array like this `serialize(["Hello \"'world'\""]`)` will give you a string of `a:1:{i:0;s:15:"Hello "'world'"";}` which has no sane way of consuming the serialized string as a unit apart from running it back through the serializer.

Comment: @Sherif  I can see why this would look bad. I put the info into a queue on one side and retrieve it on the other. It isnt going into a database at all im just taking an existing fields and values string and ripping through them to pull out the data I want. I decided the best way to do this was to go back to where it originates and just pass the array through instead of the imploded string, now I have the power to do whatever I want with it without worrying about anything. I was just hoping I could avoid that but it is the best way.

Comment: Clearly the best way isn't the way that has painted you into a corner. Perhaps choose a better serialization format during transport so that you don't run into this issue? Personally, I would just go with JSON.